Haproxy 2.5.0 is killed right after doing a docker compose up -d
I use 4 docker containers to run my application:
One for mongoDB, one for apostrophe
3 of them are just fine but, the haproxy is killed just after doing a docker compose up -d.
Unfortunatly, I'm not able to run my haproxu container. It looks like starting at first, but then while checking docker ps it is not present in the list.
Here is my config docker-compose.yml :
 ```version: '3.4'
services:
  astro:
    command: tail -f /dev/null
  apostrophe:
    command: tail -f /dev/null
  haproxy:
    command: tail -f /dev/null```

So roght now I have this : 
```CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                      NAMES
ecaa68d94c73   haproxy:2.5.0        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   project-haproxy-1
d9e938b2ef07   mongo:6              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp                              project-mongodb-1
0426f9e80cba   project-apostrophe   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp                                  project-apostrophe-1
3f2ed94657d0   project-astro        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp, :::4000->4000/tcp                                  project-astro-1
```

While doing docker compose exec haproxy sh and testing this command haproxy -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg I got this : 

```
$ ls -l /etc/ssl/private/local.dgadteamdev.com.pem
-rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1000 3008 Apr  3 13:18 /etc/ssl/private/local.dgadteamdev.com.pem
$ haproxy -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg   
[NOTICE]   (14) : haproxy version is 2.5.0-f2e0833
[NOTICE]   (14) : path to executable is /usr/local/sbin/haproxy
[ALERT]    (14) : Not enough memory to allocate 1073741816 entries for fdtab!
[ALERT]    (14) : No polling mechanism available.
  It is likely that haproxy was built with TARGET=generic and that FD_SETSIZE
  is too low on this platform to support maxconn and the number of listeners
  and servers. You should rebuild haproxy specifying your system using TARGET=
  in order to support other polling systems (poll, epoll, kqueue) or reduce the
  global maxconn setting to accommodate the system's limitation. For reference,
  FD_SETSIZE=1024 on this system, global.maxconn=536870878 resulting in a maximum of
  1073741816 file descriptors. You should thus reduce global.maxconn by 536870396. Also,
  check build settings using 'haproxy -vv'.

```

And while doing haproxy -vv here is the result :

```

    $ haproxy -vv 
    HAProxy version 2.5.0-f2e0833 2021/11/23 - https://haproxy.org/
    Status: stable branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q1 2023.
    Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.5.0.html
    Running on: Linux 6.6.14-200.fc39.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 26 20:12:16 UTC 2024 x86_64
    Build options :
      TARGET  = linux-glibc
      CPU     = generic
      CC      = cc
      CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-cast-function-type -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference
      OPTIONS = USE_PCRE2=1 USE_PCRE2_JIT=1 USE_GETADDRINFO=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_PROMEX=1
      DEBUG   = 
    
    Feature list : +EPOLL -KQUEUE +NETFILTER -PCRE -PCRE_JIT +PCRE2 +PCRE2_JIT +POLL +THREAD +BACKTRACE -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +TPROXY +LINUX_TPROXY +LINUX_SPLICE +LIBCRYPT +CRYPT_H +GETADDRINFO +OPENSSL +LUA +ACCEPT4 -CLOSEFROM -ZLIB +SLZ +CPU_AFFINITY +TFO +NS +DL +RT -DEVICEATLAS -51DEGREES -WURFL -SYSTEMD -OBSOLETE_LINKER +PRCTL -PROCCTL +THREAD_DUMP -EVPORTS -OT -QUIC +PROMEX -MEMORY_PROFILING
    
    Default settings :
      bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200
    
    Built with multi-threading support (MAX_THREADS=64, default=16).
    Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
    Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
    OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
    OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
    OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
    Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.3
    Built with the Prometheus exporter as a service
    Built with network namespace support.
    Built with libslz for stateless compression.
    Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
    Support for malloc_trim() is enabled.
    Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
    Built with PCRE2 version : 10.36 2020-12-04
    PCRE2 library supports JIT : yes
    Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
    Built with gcc compiler version 10.2.1 20210110
    
    Available polling systems :
          epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
           poll : pref=200,  test result OK
         select : pref=150,  test result OK
    Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
    
    Available multiplexer protocols :
    (protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
                  h2 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H2       flags=HTX|CLEAN_ABRT|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
                fcgi : mode=HTTP       side=BE        mux=FCGI     flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
           <default> : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1       flags=HTX
                  h1 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1       flags=HTX|NO_UPG
           <default> : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS     flags=
                none : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS     flags=NO_UPG
    
    Available services : prometheus-exporter
    Available filters :
            [SPOE] spoe
            [CACHE] cache
            [FCGI] fcgi-app
            [COMP] compression
            [TRACE] trace

```

What should I do ? I don't know how to allocate more memory to it.
Can you help me please ? 
Thanks


Moving to a newer version of HaProxy can possibly help you solve this issue.
The next version, 2.6 added the fd-hard-limit configuration which addresses these kind of scenarios, the configuration is still present in all the following newer versions up to the current 3.0.
HaProxy 2.6 documentation excerpt follows

fd-hard-limit <number>
Sets an upper bound to the maximum number of
file descriptors that the process will use, regardless of system
limits. While "ulimit-n" and "maxconn" may be used to enforce a value,
when they are not set, the process will be limited to the hard limit
of the RLIMIT_NOFILE setting as reported by "ulimit -n -H". But some
modern operating systems are now allowing extremely large values here
(in the order of 1 billion), which will consume way too much RAM for
regular usage. The fd-hard-limit setting is provided to enforce a
possibly lower bound to this limit. This means that it will always
respect the system-imposed limits when they are below  but the
specified value will be used if system-imposed limits are higher. In
the example below, no other setting is specified and the maxconn value
will automatically adapt to the lower of "fd-hard-limit" and the
system-imposed limit:
global
    # use as many FDs as possible but no more than 50000
    fd-hard-limit 50000

See also: ulimit-n, maxconn

Additional reference: https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/issues/180
